# How to synchronise Core Data relationships?

Tags: mysql, ios, sqlite, core-data, relationships

I'm creating an app that pulls data from a web server (MySQL), parses it and stores it in a SQLite database using Core Data.

The MySQL database has a 'words' table. Each word can be in a 'category'. So the words table has a field for 'category_id' to join the tables.

I'm having some trouble getting my head around how to replicate this locally in my app. I currently have entities matching the structure of the MySQL database, but no relationships. It seems like in my 'words' entity I shouldn't need the 'category_id' field (I should instead have a one-to-one 'category' relation set-up).

I'm confused as to how to keep this Core Data relationship in sync with the web server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an `Entity` for `Word` and `Category` you will need to make a relationship (naming may be a bit hazy). Also assuming a `Category` can have many words and

```
// Word Entity
Relationship    Destination    Inverse
category        Categories     words

// Category Entity
Relationship    Destination   Inverse
words           Word          category       // To-Many relationship
```

You are correct you would not need the category_id field as all relationships are managed through the object graph that Core Data maintains. You will still need a primary key like `server_id` (or similar) in each entity or you will have trouble updating/finding already saved objects.

This is how I deal with syncing data from an external database (I use RESTful interfaces with JSON but that does not really matter)

1. Grab the feed sorted by server_id
2. Get the primary keys (server_id) of all the objects in the feed
3. Perform a fetch using the a predicate like `... @"(serverId IN %@)", primaryKeys`
   which is sorted by the primary key.
4. Step through each array. If the fetch result has my record then I update it. If it does not then I insert a new one.
5. You would need to do this for both `Word` and `Category`
6. Next fetch all objects that form part of a relationship
7. Use the appropriate methods generated by core data for adding objects. e.g. something like `[myArticle addWords:[NSSet setWithObjects:word1, word2, word3, nil];

It's hard for me to test but this should give you a starting point?
Good to see a fellow Shiny course attendee using stack overflow - it's not just me

Comment: Thanks for the response...When you say 'appropriate methods generated by core data' what exactly do you mean? Have you generated models automatically using XCode?

Comment: I generally edit the `model` using the WYSIWYG then do `File->New->New File->Core Data->NSManagedObjectSubclass` and create subclass of `NSManagedObject` for each `Entity`. You can look in the `.h` file of the generated class and see the methods generated for relationships